How can I prevent my Tobii camera from turning off during Windows Hello face recognition in Windows 11?
I am using a Tobiidynavox PCEye 5 eyetracker to control my PC due to my disability.
It is Windows Hello capable, hence I set up face recognition for my Windows account (under Windows 11). It works perfectly, in principle.
However, when I don't look immediately at the camera/screen, Windows Hello switch to PIN mode after approximately 30 seconds and turns the camera off.
Firstly, I don't see any reason why this happens that quickly. Furthermore, in my case, I can't type the PIN by myself.
My question is very similar to Windows Hello camera gets turned off after some time - how to increase or disable this timeout? which however didn't got any real answers.
Is there any possibility to prolong the time for facial recognition? Or even to disable the timeout completely?

I assume if you have no pin, you’ll be asked, for a password instead?

no, on the lock screen, there is then only displayed that I should type my PIN... Anyway, password would be also impossible for me to type because I would need my eyetracker which however turns off automatically when facial recognition doesn't work.

Your description does not make sense, I am suggesting you explicitly disable your Windows Hello pin, leaving only Windows Hello factual recognition.  Are you saying even if you disable the pin, you are then, prompted to enter a pin?

How can I disable PIN when I have facial recognition turned on?? That would be great if it's possible..
